# Python Selenium copying text from div, 3

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do you take the text "BURGUNDY" from the HTML code:

`<span class = "style_title_section__title__1z8gk">`

`<div class = "row"><div class = "col-md-12"></div>BURGUNDY</div>`

`<div class = "row"><div class = "col-md-12"></div>randomTxt</div>`

`</span>`

I keep getting this from the console: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

I tried another way and still received this:
search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//div[@class='col-md-12']"))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I can't figure it out, please help me out using python or Selenium, thank you!

Comment: Hi, you can use the function of `find_element_by_css_selector()`. The Selenium documentation regarding how to locate elements is so useful in its [webpage](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
from lxml import html
html_code = '''
<span class = "style_title_section__title__1z8gk">

<div class = "row"><div class = "col-md-12"></div>BURGUNDY</div>

<div class = "row"><div class = "col-md-12"></div>randomTxt</div>

</span>
'''

tree = html.fromstring(html_code)

your_target_txt = tree.xpath('//span/div/text()')[0]
print(your_target_txt)

your_target_txt = tree.xpath('(//span/div)[1]/text()')[0]
print(your_target_txt)
```